# TM1 Rules - reversed the rule to write the feeder, still not working

Tags: cognos-tm1

I've been re-arranging the same cube feeder with no success. I do not know why this feeder is
not working for the rule below.
There are numbers loaded in the element 'GSOP Rod & bar', and all I want to do is allocate that by using year 2023 % distribution. The numbers all sit in the same cube "PS Sale". Any hints appreciated.

```
    FEEDSTRINGS; 
    SKIPCHECK;
    #EndRegion
    
    
    #Region load actuals to working forecast versions ['Working Forecast'] = N:     If 
    (DB('cen_Assumption',!Version,!Year,!Month,'No Company','No Currency','Month contains 
    Actuals','Numeric') = 1,    ['Actual'],     Continue);  
    
                    
    
    ['Working Forecast', '2145' , 'NZD' ,  'Tonnes' ] = N:
    
    IF ( Attrs( 'PS Market' , !PS Market , 'Dom_Exp' ) @= 'Domestic'  ,
    IF(   ELISANC(  'PS Item Class'  , 'M' , !PS Item Class ) =1 ,
    
   DB( 'PS Sales' , 'Actual' , '2023' , 'All Months' ,  '2145' , 'NZD' ,  !PS Market ,  !PS 
    Customer Branch Code , !PS Item Class , 'Tonnes' )/   

   DB( 'PS Sales' , 'Actual' , '2023' , 
    'All Months' ,  '2145' , 'NZD' , 'Domestic' , 'All Customers' , 'M' , 'Tonnes' )    *   
    
    DB( 'PS Sales' , 'Working Forecast' , !Year , !Month ,  '2145' , 'NZD' , 'Domestic Despatch' , 
    'GSOP' , 'GSOP Rod & bar' , 'Tonnes' ) , 
    
    Continue        )   
    , Continue ); 
    
    
    Feeders; 

    ['Working Forecast' , '2145' , 'NZD' , 'Domestic Despatch' , 'PS Customer Branch Code':'GSOP',
    'GSOP Rod & bar' , 'Tonnes'] => ['Working Forecast' , '2145' , 'NZD'  , 'Tonnes'];       

    ['Actual'] => ['Working Forecast'];
```